# Relations Question

Tags: relations

I have some trouble understanding relatons. Below there is a question that I am working on. I believe that the a) part its correct but I have no idea how to do the b) and c)

As part of a computer security system, you need to control which users have access to which drives. Albert has access to drives X and Z. Belinda has access to drives X, W and Z. Charlotte has access to drives V and W. Eoin has access to drives Z and V. Denoting by U the set of users and D the set of drives,

(a) Give the relation R on U × D which represents this information. (You may use
appropriate abbreviations.)  MY ANSWER IS BELOW... correct me if I'm wrong

R= {(A,X),(A,Z),(B,X),(B,W),(B,Z),(C,V),(C,W),(E,Z),(E,V)}

(b) Find the combination of projection and inverse projection maps which find those
users with access to drive Z.

(c) Find the combination of projection and inverse projection maps which find drives
accessible to both Albert and Eoin.

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohjEY.png)

Comment: What difficulty are you actually having?  Do the terms *projection* and *inverse* have a clear meaning to you?  Are you unsure what to write down, despite knowing how to apply the relation from (a) to determine the users in (b) and the drives in (c)?

Comment: I have problems understating these terms. But also not sure of If im correct in (a), got no idea how to start (b) and (c)

Comment: i have made a typo sorry , I havenow corrected to (C,V)

Comment: I have uploaded the question from my practice paper hope it helps

Comment: no i dont understand

Comment: oh my god now , i get it my bad. yeah you are right another typo